Unable to Connect to Amazon Redshift Serverless from Python - Connection Timeout
I've been trying to connect to my Amazon Redshift Serverless instance from Python, using the redshift_connector package, but I keep encountering a connection timeout error.
This is how I try to connect:

host="redshift-host"
database="dev"
port=5439
user="admin"
password="the-admin-password"
serverless_acct_id="my_serverless_account_id"
serverless_work_group="my_workgroup_name"

# Option 1

conn = redshift_connector.connect(

    iam=True,
    host=host,
    database=database,
    access_key_id="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
    secret_access_key="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
    session_token="AWS_SESSION_TOKEN",
    region="eu-north-1",
    is_serverless=True,
    serverless_acct_id=serverless_acct_id,
    serverless_work_group=serverless_work_group
)

# Option 2

conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host=host,
    database=database,
    port=port,
    user=user,
    password=password,
)

Both of these fail with:
 raise OperationalError("connection time out", timeout_error) redshift_connector.error.OperationalError: ('connection time out', TimeoutError(60, 'Operation timed out'))
Here are the details of my setup and what I've tried so far:
What I've Checked:

Public Accessibility: Confirmed that the Redshift serverless endpoint is set to publicly accessible.
Security Groups: Ensured that the security group allows inbound traffic on port 5439 from 0.0.0.0/0.
Network ACLs: Verified that the Network ACLs for the subnet do not block inbound or outbound traffic on port 5439.
Route Table: Checked that the subnet route table includes a route to an Internet Gateway (0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-XXXXXXXX).
Local Firewall: No firewall rules blocking out outbound traffic blocking on port 5439.

To me it seems like everything should be set up correctly and I should be able to connect. However I still keep getting timeout error. What am I doing wrong?
I tried allowing all traffic in the security group and setting publicly accessible to True. I expected to be able to connect, but it is timing out.
Update:
I tried connecting to the DB though DBeaver using the JDBC connection, that is also failing with error: Connection attempt timed out.
So it seems to me like there is something with the way the network is setup that does not allow incoming connections...

Does dbeaver connect to it on the machine you are trying to run the python on?  If not then the problem isn't the python.

Tried connecting with dbeaver now, and it also gives error:
Connection attempt timed out.

I managed to get connected!
The redshift serverless workspace was connected to several subnets, and some of them were private. When choosing only the public subnets I was able to connect.
